# Unable to Grab error message from website and print in Eclipse console using Selenium(java)

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

**I am trying to get the Error message printed in SalesForce website for entering incorrect username and password**

```
package today;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Gmail {

public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");      WebDriver mail=new ChromeDriver();
mail.get("https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=in");


mail.findElement(By.cssSelector("#username")).sendKeys("judinkp@gmail.com");
mail.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"password\"]")).sendKeys("23232");

mail.findElement(By.id("Login")).click();

System.out.println(mail.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='error']")).getText());
    }
}
```

My Script runs till it clicks on `Login` but the Error message printed in website is not getting printed in my console , I am getting below error message

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='loginError']"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)
```

The Xpath is Browser given Xpath.

Website Link:https: [//login.salesforce.com/?locale=in](http://%20//login.salesforce.com/?locale=in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try below solution:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class LoginScreen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("launching chrome browser");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");  



        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.navigate().to("https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=in");
        driver.get("https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=in");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#username")).sendKeys("judinkp@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("23232");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Login")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
        WebElement error= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("error")));  
        System.out.println(error.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new to Coding , can you please post with full program

Comment: Great !! would you kind enough to hit update button from your end.so that other people can also refer above solution

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with CSS and Xpath locators.

Try with System.out.println(mail.findElement(By.id("error")).getText()); it should print out in the console.